# Symfony 1.4 with ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse

Tags: symfony1, proxy, mod-proxy

I recently setup a two virtualhosts that is accessible via a single domain, the first one (a splash page) accessible via the default port 80 (`https://my.domain.com/`), and the other (the symfony application) accessible through the port 9000 (`https://my.domain.com:9000/`).

I setup a ProxyPass and ProxypassReverse directive on the first virtualhost to access the second one via the url `https://my.domain.com/teller`, and it works, except that it overwrites the whole url when routing, the url becomes `https://my.domain.com/route` instead of my expected url of `https://my.domain.com/teller/route`

Any ideas on how I can solve this one? Thanks in advance! :D

Comment: Has this been solved yet? I'm having the exact same problem with Symfony 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this is quite easy to solve: just put all the files (don't forget .htaccess) from /htdocs into /htdocs/teller and adjust the include directives in app.php and app_dev.php, respectively. This does at least work for Symfony 2.0, I haven't tested it with earlier versions.